# Add subviews to make them centre align for parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to add some views(child) dynamically in one view(parent). So my resultant parent view will look like strip of small child views. I want to align child views in centre. Please refer attached image depicting my thinking. First view shows parent view with one child view and second view is having parent view with 2 child views.

[image]

Comment: self.parent.center=self.chiledview.center  try it

Answer (score 0):

I think the most suitable place for layout subviews for your case is implementing `-[UIView layoutSubviews]` method in your parent view. You can calculate the total width of the subviews and total amount of gaps between subviews then set frame of each subviews.